# I want to create a shell script that will create a pre-formatted file and open it in vim using a file name as an argument

Tags: bash, vim

I want to create a shell script that will create a pre-formatted file and open it in vim.

Specifically, I want to create a script called `newperl` that will allow me to type `newperl [filename]` and generate a file (using cat, echo, >, etc.) that is pre-formatted with

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.014;
```

etc.

I know how to do all the formatting etc. My problem is passing the [filename] which I type in after `newperl` to the rest of the script as an argument. How do I do that?

Comment: Adding the `vim` tag since this is more easily handled in vim itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `$1` will automatically contain the word/quoted string passed after the call to the script.

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to write a shell script. Vim already has a hook that will allow you to read in a pre-existing file when you open a new file.

First, save your perl template somewhere convenient. I keep a directory `~/.vim/new_file_templates`, containing `skeleton.pl`, `skeleton.py`, etc.

Next, add this to your `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd BufNewFile *.pl 0r ~/.vim/new_file_templates/skeleton.pl
```

This says that when you open a new file in `vim` whose name matches '*.pl', read in the contents
of `skeleton.pl` at the first line of the new file.

Then just typing

```
vim newperl.pl
```

will open a new file called 'newperl.pl' using 'skeleton.pl' as a template.

Comment: Thanks! This is an excellent answer, and it's what I will use (already created the skeleton files in fact), but I thought I should select the other answer as the correct one because it answers the question as posed, and I figure that will be more useful for if anyone asks the same question in the future. Thanks again, though!

Comment: No problem. After I posted this, it occured to me that a bash script would be better if you wanted to, say, give an option list of modules to include: `newperl test.pl List::Util File::Spec`, for example.